# How to make the background carousel pic smaller

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this carousel, and I want to make the pics on the side smaller and side pics to be a bit in the back of the front pic, like in the the photo below.

For it to be like that, shall I give different class to each picture, and modify it in the css file, or is there any other method?

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.carousel').carousel();
});
```

```css
.carousel-item{
  position: absolute;
  background-color:green;
}

img {
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'functionality/imageslider.js' %}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="{% static 'blog/imageslider.css' %}">
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-item"
        ><img src="/media/carousel-pics/photo-1454942901704-3c44c11b2ad1.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item"
        ><img src="/media/carousel-pics/photo-1454942901704-3c44c11b2ad1.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item"
        ><img src="/media/carousel-pics/photo-1454942901704-3c44c11b2ad1.jpg" alt=""/>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item"
        ><img
          src="/media/carousel-pics/photo-1454942901704-3c44c11b2ad1.jpg"
         alt=""/>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try by adding `perspective: 1000px;` to the parent element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.carousel').carousel();
});
```

```css
.carousel {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;   /* Add perspective */
}

.carousel-item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: green;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.carousel img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="//placehold.it/250x500/f00/000?text=box+1" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="//placehold.it/250x500/fff/000?text=box+2" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="//placehold.it/250x500/fff/000?text=box+3" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="//placehold.it/250x500/fff/000?text=box+4" alt="">
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```